# jenkins add new pod agent

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I have a problem with Jenkins on Kubernetes.
I installed the plugin and I success to run a build with a pod, but I have a problem the build is stuck on pending status.
when I look at the agent command I see that the agent's name is not correct.
this is the URL:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrlXXXXX/manage/computer/agent%2Dmc34m/jenkins-agent.jnlp
```

but the name of the agent is : `agent-mc34m/`

so - what is this `%2D`?
and why is he changing from `-` to `%2D`?

thank you!

Comment: It looks like the URL you are using to launch the Jenkins agent is not correct. The %2D in the URL is an encoded version of the hyphen character (-). So, when the URL is decoded, it should be - instead of %2D. This means that the URL should be `java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl XXXXX/manage/computer/agent-mc34m/jenkins-agent.jnlp`. This should fix the issue with the agent name not being correct.

Comment: Hi, yes If I change manual the URL and I put this on the pod it's work, but It needs to work automatically

Comment: If you have changed the URL manually, you may need to configure the Jenkins agent to use the new URL. You can do this by navigating to the Jenkins configuration page, selecting the agent in question, and then updating the URL field to point to the new URL. Additionally, you may need to restart the Jenkins agent for the new URL to take effect. can you have a try with this then it  work automatically

Comment: No, I can't do it because when I build a job Jenkins runs a new pod automatically with a random name, what I meant to say is if I take the URL and replace the %2D to "-" it's working, but I cant do it every time I run a job

Comment: Iam not asking to configure any new url, im asking you to update/replace the url which is working now using "-" . So, you cant do it manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL you are using to launch the Jenkins agent is not correct. The %2D in the URL is an encoded version of the hyphen character (-). So, when the URL is decoded, it should be - instead of %2D. This means that the URL should be java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl XXXXX/manage/computer/agent-mc34m/jenkins-agent.jnlp. This should fix the issue with the agent name not being correct.